# How can I rewrite this statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have declared a variable @date

```
SELECT @date = CASE 
      WHEN MAX(dt) IS NULL THEN '31/12/2009' 
      ELSE MAX(dt) + 1 
  END 
  FROM mytab
```

A code snippet where I am using the local variable

```
CASE 
  WHEN MAX(DateValue)= @date THEN NULL 
  ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, MAX(DateValue)), 103) 
END AS newdt
```

I don't want to use the @date local variable in the case statement but want to get the same effect. I tried:

```
CASE 
  WHEN MAX(DateValue)= @isnull(dt, '31/12/2009') 
  ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, MAX(DateValue)), 103) 
END AS newdt
```

but receive an error.  Any idea of getting rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, firstly you need to use

```
ISNULL(dt, '31/12/2009')
```

Without the **@**.

Secondly, you will need to give a more complete query for us to check. Also, specify the error you are receiving.

You could also include the original select in the second select. Something like this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN MAX(DateValue)= (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(dt) IS NULL THEN '31/12/2009' ELSE MAX(dt) + 1 END FROM mytab)
   ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, MAX(DateValue)), 103) 
END AS newdt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE 
  WHEN MAX(DateValue)= isnull(dt, '31/12/2009') 
  ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, MAX(DateValue)), 103) 
END AS newdt
```